# JS Object Key / Value Addition

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, increment

I'm trying to understand the syntax of a solution I found.

The problem:
Write a function that accepts a string of lowercase letters as an argument, and that it should return an object containing the number of times each letter appeared in the string.

The solution:

```
function analyzeFrequencies(string) {
    const frequenciesObj = {};
    for (let i of string) {
        frequenciesObj[i] = frequenciesObj[i] + 1 || 1;
    }
    return frequenciesObj;
}
```

I understand line one, where the function is created and a parameter is fed.

I understand line two, where an empty object is creased.

I sort of understand line three, where a for loop is created to comb through a variable as long as there is an index.

I don't understand line four at all. From left to right it seems like `frequenciesObj[i] =` is assigning a value to the index of the object. `= frequenciesObj[i]` is currently empty? `+ 1 || 1`  it either adds one, or sets one?

How does it decide to set one or add one?
How does it ever add a key -- letter of a string -- to the object?

Comment: Using for..of, `i` is not the index, it's the value itself. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

Comment: debug and learn `for (let i of string) { console.log(i, frequenciesObj[i], frequenciesObj[i] + 1);`

Comment: The name of the variable `i` is very unfortunate. It *suggests* an index, but it isn't. It should better be named `letter` or something else that *describes* what it is.

Comment: personally I would have written it as `frequenciesObj[i] = (frequenciesObj[i] || 0) + 1;`

Answer (score -1):

**`frequenciesObj[i] = frequenciesObj[i] + 1 || 1;`**
this means if frequenciesObj[i] + 1 returns true then it will add the frequenciesObj[i] value with 1 . and if in case a error occured to add the value with 1 then the next only 1 will be added to the dictionary

Comment: *"in case a error occurred"*: no error occurs.

Comment: Wait, would it evaluate to as frequenciesObj[i] + (1 || 1); or as (frequenciesObj[i] + 1) || 1;

Comment: frequenciesObj[i] + (1 || 1); // invalid syntax. (frequenciesObj[i] + 1) || 1; if (frequenciesObj[i] + 1 is evluated as true then the addition will be stored in empty object else if an error ocuues then only 1 will be stored in the empty object